# nginx rewrite POST request

Tags: post, nginx, url-rewriting, request

I need send POST request to my nginx frontend server which should redirect it to upstream servers.
In details:

send request to http://192.168.0.10/foo/bar/blah and URL in this request should be changed to http://192.168.0.21[22,23]:8080/foo/blah

```
upstream myapp {
   server 192.168.0.21:8080;
   server 192.168.0.22:8080;
   server 192.168.0.23:8080;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

   location /foo/bar/blah/ {
      rewrite ^/foo/blah^/ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://myapp;
   }
```

but in nginx error log I see that my request changed from POST to GET and also seems didn't change URL:

```
"POST /foo/bar/blah HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
"GET /foo/bar/blah/ HTTP/1.1" 404 117 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
```

How can I keep my POST request and change the URL?

Also about my rewrite rule

```
      rewrite ^/foo/blah^/ /$1 break;
```

I found a lot of examples for changing URL and all of them looks the same.
And it is really strange for me, how this rewrite rule can change URL from /foo/bar/blah/ to /foo/blah/:
in documentaion says:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

> If the specified regular expression matches a request URI, URI is
>   changed as specified in the replacement string.

but in my case request URI is /foo/bar/blah/ so regular expression /foo/blah^/ doesn't matches URI, so this rule shouldn't work.
Am I right?

Would be helpful any advises.

**UPD:**
fixed:

```
 location = /foo/bar/blah {
          proxy_pass http://myapp/foo/blah;
       }
```

Comment: Well if you POST to `/foo/bar/blah`, then not even `location /foo/bar/blah/` should match that in the first place (no trailing slash.) // If you want the client to not change the request method on a redirect, then you need to use a `307 Temporary Redirect`. But it looks like you don’t want to actually redirect the client, but pass the data on internally, so that your nginx acts as a proxy. Those are different things …

Comment: so how to create the right rule? I just deleted trailing slash in my rewrite and it seems starts send POST but still doesn't rewrite URI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess, you don't need rewrite.

```
location /foo/bar/ {
  proxy_pass http://myapp/;
}
```

This should remove `/foo/bar` part from proxied URL.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to 

    `location = /foo/bar/blah {
            proxy_pass http://myapp/foo/blah;
    }`
   
and it works as expected.

Comment: @TravErse You should accept this answer so Alexey gets credit